# Selenium without RC: Connection Refused

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium on my local computer, but sometimes I get a socket error that I don't fully understand. So far, restarting the (Python) application has worked for me.

What could be causing this?

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=someProfile)
driver.get(someLink)
```

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-cdc559ddfda1>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.get(link)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 245, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 231, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 425, in _request
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1083, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1128, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1079, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 911, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 854, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 826, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/foo/.conda/envs/myenv3/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks the problem is related to some http libraries which ignores the proxy settings. what version of python you are using ? try using Python 2.x and see how it goes.